# find duplicate 1st field and concat its values in single line

Tags: text-processing, awk, uniq, yaml

I have a file that has entries in `key: value` format like the below:

cat data.txt

```
name: 'tom'
tom_age: '31'
status_tom_mar: 'yes'
school: 'anne'
fd_year_anne: '1987'
name: 'hmz'
hmz_age: '21'
status_hmz_mar: 'no'
school: 'svp'
fd_year_svp: '1982'
name: 'toli'
toli_age: '41'
```

and likewise ...

I need to find and print only those `key: value` that have duplicate keys as a single entry.

The below code gets me the duplicate keys

```
cat data.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort  | uniq -d
name:
school:
```

However, I want the output where I wish to concatenate the values of duplicate keys in one line.

Expected output:

```
name: ['tom', 'hmz', 'toli']
school: ['anne', 'svp']
tom_age: '31'
status_tom_mar: 'yes'
fd_year_anne: '1987'
hmz_age: '21'
status_hmz_mar: 'no'
fd_year_svp: '1982'
toli_age: '41'
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Is this a YAML file that you are manipulating? If so use a syntax aware parser like yq

Comment: Yes yaml, Can you share command for yq that will help meet the requirement? Never heard of it before

Comment: But this is not valid `yaml`.

Comment: Correct but i need to convert this to a valid yaml. The file data.txt is not in our control

Comment: but your output is also not valid yaml.

Comment: Its a variable file that is read by ansible and works alright

Comment: Your `hmz_age` and `fd_year_anne` is duplicated in the output.

Comment: @pLumo that was due to overlook. I made the corrections in original post

Comment: I'm not supposed to care about what you want, but it's hard to ignore that `<name>_age`, `status_<name>_mar` and `fd_year_<school>` cry out for a different record structur.

Comment: @Philippos what makes you think you're "not supposed to care about what you want"?   Sometimes (often, even) the right answer to a problem involves pointing out **better** ways of doing things.....and the data samples shown here are, as you say, crying out for [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).   And if whatever generates these psuedo-yaml files can't be fixed, then any tool that has to process them absolutely **should** attempt to do that.  Even if the OP explicitly asks for garbage input data to be converted into another equally-garbage output format.

Comment: I feel embarrassed reading the last line :) @cas

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to cause embarrassment, but it's true: the output format you asked for is no better than the input. It should be converted into some kind of record format, where each record has the same fields - name, age, marital status, fd year, etc instead of having unique keys (like hmz_age or fd_year_anne) randomly scattered throughout the data (probably grown into a horrible mess with random additions rather than designed). Depending on what you're going to use the data for, each record should probably also have some kind of unique identifier field (and names certainly aren't unique)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk -F': ' '
{
    count[$1]++; 
    data[$1] = $1 in data ? data[$1]", "$2 : $2 
} 
END { 
    for (id in count) { 
        printf "%s: ",id; 
        print (count[id]>1 ? "[ "data[id]" ]" : data[id])
    }
}' data.txt 
hmz_age: '21'
tom_age: '31'
fd_year_anne: '1987'
school: [ 'anne', 'svp' ]
name: [ 'tom', 'hmz', 'toli' ]
toli_age: '41'
fd_year_svp: '1982'
status_hmz_mar: 'no'
status_tom_mar: 'yes'
```

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -F: -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}},$F[1]; 
        END{ 
            for $key (keys(%k)){ 
                $data=""; 
                if(scalar(@{$k{$key}})>1){ 
                    $data="[" . join(",",@{$k{$key}}) . "]"; 
                } 
                else{
                    $data=${$k{$key}}[0];
                }
                print "$key: $data"
            }
        }' data.txt 
status_tom_mar:  'yes'
fd_year_anne:  '1987'
tom_age:  '31'
toli_age:  '41'
fd_year_svp:  '1982'
hmz_age:  '21'
school: [ 'anne', 'svp']
name: [ 'tom', 'hmz', 'toli']
status_hmz_mar:  'no'
```

Or, a bit easier to understand maybe:

```
perl -F: -lane '@fields=@F; 
                push @{$key_hash{$fields[0]}},$fields[1]; 
                END{ 
                    for $key (keys(%key_hash)){ 
                        $data=""; 
                        @key_data=@{$key_hash{$key}};
                        if(scalar(@key_data)>1){ 
                           $data="[" . join(",", @key_data) . "]"; 
                        } 
                        else{
                            $data=$key_data[0]
                        }
                        print "$key: $data"
                    }
                }' data.txt
```

Comment: I don't have perl.. Can i have non perl solution please

Comment: @Ashar I added an awk approach. But you don't have perl? What operating system is this? AIX? Please always mention your OS in the question because we need to know what tools and what versions of the tools are available.

Answer (score 4):

A short `awk` program will achieve this for you

```
awk -F': ' '
    # Every line of input; fields split at colon+space
    {
        # Append a comma if we have previous items
        if (h[$1] > "") { h[$1] = h[$1] ", " };

        # Append the item and increment the count
        h[$1] = h[$1] $2;
        i[$1]++
    }

    # Finally
    END {
        # Iterate across all the keys we have found
        for (k in h) {
            if (i[k] > 1) { p = "[%s]" } else { p = "%s" };
            printf "%s: " p "\n", k, h[k]
        }
    }
' data.txt
```

Output

```
hmz_age: ['21', '41']
tom_age: '31'
fd_year_anne: ['1987', '1982']
school: ['anne', 'svp']
name: ['tom', 'hmz', 'toli']
status_hmz_mar: 'no'
status_tom_mar: 'yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:
`awk '{arr[$1][length(arr[$1])+1]=$2}; END {for (i in arr) {printf i;if (length(arr[i])>1) {xc=" [";for (rr in arr[i]) {printf xc;printf arr[i][rr];xc=","} print "]"} else print arr[i][length(arr[i])]} }' data.txt`

Output:

```
hmz_age:'21'
fd_year_svp:'1982'
fd_year_anne:'1987'
name: ['tom','hmz','toli']
school: ['anne','svp']
status_tom_mar:'yes'
tom_age:'31'
toli_age:'41'
status_hmz_mar:'no'
```

Comment: I would suggest that your answer would be greatly improved if you were to explain how it works. Not everyone will be able to understand your code

Comment: Only _GNU_ awk has true array of array (not the traditional [i,j,...] using SUBSEP)

Comment: Never do `printf foo` for any input data as it'll fail when that data contains printf formatting chars like `%s`, use `printf "%s", foo` instead.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i think that `gawk` was implicit. this and a few else can apply `length` to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6):

```perl
raku -e 'my %h; for lines() {%h.=append: .split(":").map(*.trim).hash}; .say for %h;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my %h.=append: .split(":").map(*.trim).hash for lines; .say for %h;'
```

With Raku, you have hash functionalities built in (see the docs pages at bottom). Briefly, the code above takes `lines`, `split`s on `":"` colon, `trim`s whitespace from resulting 2 elements, and generates a `hash` (i.e. key-value pair). Each line's hash is then `append`ed to the named `%h` (hash) object, and values are appropriately added to their respective keys.

Sample Input:

```
name: 'tom'
tom_age: '31'
status_tom_mar: 'yes'
school: 'anne'
fd_year_anne: '1987'
name: 'hmz'
hmz_age: '21'
status_hmz_mar: 'no'
school: 'svp'
fd_year_svp: '1982'
name: 'toli'
toli_age: '41'
```

Sample Output:

```
hmz_age => '21'
fd_year_svp => '1982'
status_tom_mar => 'yes'
fd_year_anne => '1987'
school => ['anne' 'svp']
status_hmz_mar => 'no'
tom_age => '31'
name => ['tom' 'hmz' 'toli']
toli_age => '41'
```

Once your data is in the `%h` object you can manipulate output. Substituting `.put` for `.say` in the code above gives tab-separated (not `=>` separated) return. Furthermore, you can pull out values associated with individual keys like so (add below as a final statement):

```perl
say %h<name>;'
['tom' 'hmz' 'toli']
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://docs.raku.org/language/101-basics#Hashes

Answer (score -1):

step1

```
for i in $(awk -F ":" '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}' file.txt | awk '$NF>1{print $1}'|tac); do grep "^$i" file.txt >/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then awk -v i="$i" -F ":" '$1 == i{print $2}' file.txt|awk 'END{print "\n"}ORS=","'|sed "s/^,//g"|sed "s/,$//g"|awk -v i="$i" '{print i":["$0"]"}';else grep -v "^$i" file.txt;fi; done >output.txt
```

step2

```
for i in $(awk -F ":" '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}' file.txt| awk '$NF==1'); do awk -v i="$i" -F ":" '$1 ~ i' file.txt; done >>output.txt
```

output

```
name: ['tom', 'hmz', 'toli']
school: ['anne', 'svp']
tom_age: '31'
status_tom_mar: 'yes'
fd_year_anne: '1987'
hmz_age: '21'
status_hmz_mar: 'no'
fd_year_svp: '1982'
toli_age: '41'
```